# Graph API: Access Token in paging, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, paging, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to grab some information from my facebook page to display on a website. I keep the access token in my php files and make a call to the graph API using curl in order to keep it hidden. However, since you can see the results, my access token appears in the "paging" area like this:

```
"paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/[MY_ID]/posts?fields=id,from,message,icon,created_time,updated_time&limit=10&access_token=[MY_TOKEN]&since=1348180212&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/[MY_ID]/posts?fields=id,from,message,icon,created_time,updated_time&limit=10&access_token=[MY_TOKEN]&until=1348016106"
   }
```

There's no way to remove the paging section when more content is available, correct? I also can't use the curl option to not immediately print out the results (due to server restrictions) so I can't capture the results first to do what I want with them. Am I approaching this whole thing wrong, or is there a parameter I can send over that can solve this? Thank you very much for any help and insights!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it turned out to be an insanely random routing issue.